# update nested attribute: WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, nested-attributes, mass-assignment

I spent so much time on this and lost half my hair by pulling it. Help.

`user`:

```
    has_may :rights
    attr_accessible :rights_attributes
```

`right`:

```
    belongs_to :user
    attr_accessible :user_id, :pgd_id, :link_id
```

View:

```
<%= semantic_form_for @user, :url => {:action => "rightsupdate", :id => @user.id} do |f| %>$
  <%= f.inputs do %>$
    <%= f.input :pgds, :as => :check_boxes, :required => false %>$
  <% end %>$
    <%= f.input :link_id, :value => @owner.link_id, :as => :hidden %>$
    <%= f.buttons %>$
<% end %>$
```

but when I update it keeps saying:

```
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: pgd_ids, link_id
```

I can bypass the `pdg` by adding `:pgd_ids` to the user `attr_accessible` but not the `link_id`. The `link_id` is inserted as `NULL`.

Comment: sorry the code outline got messed up. It was working fine when I added it

Comment: I fiddled with it a little bit -- you need blank lines to separate paragraphs from code formatting.

Comment: you have a typo in your user model. it should be: `has_many :rights`

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make sure that the model includes `accepts_nested_attributes`.

user.rb

```
attr_accessible :rights_attributes
has_may :rights
accepts_nested_attributes :rights
```

You then need to wrap the rights fields into a `fields_for` block. It looks like you are using Formtastic, which I'm not familiar with but I think it should look something like this:

```
<%= semantic_form_for @user, :url => {:action => "rightsupdate", :id => @user.id} do |f| %> 
  <%= f.semantic_fields_for :rights do |builder| %>
    <%= builder.inputs do %>
      <%= builder.input :pgds, :as => :check_boxes, :required => false %>
    <% end %>
    <%= builder.input :link_id, :value => @owner.link_id, :as => :hidden %>
    <%= builder.buttons %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

[Railscasts](http://railscasts.com) have a number of free screencasts on nested forms which would be worth checking out the above code doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks. accepts_nested_attributes_for :rights is already there. your view code ended up duplicating the options. I'll try modifying it.

Comment: The above solution does not update. but thanks for the response @nmott my old one still says can't mass update